# Sqlite WHERE LIKE statement c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a variable `fav` which will contain values separated by a comma such as "a,b,c". In `Table1` I have a column called `Name` with values "a" "b" "c" in different rows. I would like for the query below to return a, b and c however it currently returns nothing and doesn't crash. Thanks for any help.

```
public IEnumerable<Table1> Method1()
{
    return conn.Query<Table1>("SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE [Name] LIKE '" + "%" + fav + "%" + "'");
}
```

Comment: you need to split the comma separated string and then use an  IN clause with a table valued parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'IN' rather than 'LIKE'

```
public IEnumerable<Table1> Method1()
    {
        string StrSql = "Select * From [Table1] Where [Name] in (";
        List<string> par = fav.Split(',').ToList();
        foreach (string _par in par)
        {
            StrSql += "'" + _par + "'";
            if (_par != par.Last())
            {
                StrSql += ',';
            }
            else
            {
                StrSql += ")";
            }
        }
        return conn.Query<Table1>(StrSql);
    }
```

Comment: String values need to be quoted. Or use parameters.